# Solve the system of equations for x and y

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

Solve the system of equations for $x$ and $y$:

$$
\left(\frac{x}{8-2y}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{y}{-4}\right)^2=4 \\
\frac{x}{8-2y} + \frac{x}{-2}=1
$$

I used Lagrange multipliers with multiple constraints to get to this point. I was told to use maple but it is giving out a very strange answer. Apparently the computations are feasible by hand but I am not sure how to go about solving this for all potential values of $x$ and $y$. Help!

Comment: Can you put your equations inside the question, instead of in the title? Also please use LaTeX to format your equations. As of now they are almost impossible to read

Comment: I'm confused... Lagrange multipliers to solve a system of algebraic equations? Or is this intended to be an optimization problem subject to a constraint?

Comment: It was an optimization problem subject to two constraints. I used lagrange multipliers and ended up with a system of two equations. I know need to solve for x and y to find all potential optimal points but I am not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Is that second equation correct.  As it stands, it is easily solved for $x$ and thus substituted into first equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you solve the second equation for $y$, you get:

$$y = \dfrac{3 x+8}{x+2}$$

Substituting this into the first equation, you get an expression in $x$, as:

$$4 x^4+32 x^3+23 x^2-176 x - 256 = 0$$

You can either find the [*exact roots to this quartic equation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) or use Netwon's Method or equivalent for numerical results.

This gives you two real and two imaginary roots, but I will assume you only care about the real ones.

All that is left after finding those two real (unless you also want imaginary) $x$ roots is to substitute them into your equation for the $y's$, resulting in:

$$(x, y) = (-6.1942314281353956211,~2.5231545911883245705)$$

$$(x, y) = (2.3578739564003400098,   3.4589393865012162370)$$